# What would perfumes be made of for a species that evolved from flowers?

Tags: flora

Naturally they wouldn't use flowers as a fragrance, that would just be ridiculous.
And in case it matters, they're also agnostic.

Comment: First, would they even have an olfactory sense? They're not going to need to manipulate their natural flowery smell if they can't smell anything in the first place.

Comment: What does agnosticism have to do with this?

Comment: @HDE226868 - Religious flowers realize foreign scents are blasphemy and would go to war to prevent others from doing so.  duh. ;)

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to take a crack at an answer, but I'm going to need to break down some terms here.

Perfumes are a small chemical mixture that appeal to one of our primary senses (smell); disregarding the social reasons for this its a pretty basic premise.

As FrostFyre notes in his comment to your question it would be a long shot that the flowers even smell things (rough assumption based on earth flowers) but going back to my stripped down definition a perfume for a flower would simply need to be a chemical mixture that appeals to a primary sense.

For a flower the olfactory sense may be replaced by a sort of "photosynthetic scent" an ability to taste/smell the wavelength of light in a given area. So your flowers may like the "smell" of a primarily red/blue wavelength light source. In this sense they may manufacture bottles of synthetic light sources that match good "smelling" wavelength bands/combinations. The sources may be varied; bio-luminescence, chemical (like our glow sticks), or possibly radioactive sources to produce [radioluminescence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radioluminescence) (assuming the radiation doesn't affect them the same way it does us).

So they would dab on some glowing liquid and other flowers around them would be able to enjoy the "scent."